# On showing that $ab^k=n_k\pi+r_k \implies\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(ab^k)^2<\infty\Longleftrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k^2<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $b > 1, a\neq 0$ and write $ab^k=n_k\pi + r_k, n_k \in\mathbb{Z}, -\pi/2\leq r_k<\pi/2$. A book I am reading claims that then as $0\leq \sin(ab^k)^2 = \sin(r_k)^2 \leq 1$, it follows that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(ab^k)^2 < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r_k^2 < \infty$. Is there some good convergence test you can apply to the particular trigonometric series or does this proof require some other approach? My bag of tools regarding trigonometric series is quite lacking and the only thing that comes to my mind is somehow applying the Euler's identity to this case.

Comment: $\sin (ab^{k})=\pm \sin ( r_k) \sim \pm r_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It remains to show that for a sequence $(r_k)$ with $|r_k| \le \pi/2$
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin(r_k)^2 < \infty \iff \sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k^2 < \infty \, .
$$

Because of the restriction of the $r_k$ we can use [Jordan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality):
$$
 \frac{4}{\pi^2} r_k^2 \le \sin(r_k)^2 \le r_k^2 
$$
and now the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) gives the desired equivalence.

*Remark:* The convergence $\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k^2  $ does always imply the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sin(r_k)^2$, but the other direction would be wrong without some restriction on the $r_k$, as can be seen by choosing $r_k = \pi$.